# Django not connecting to remote MySQL db: MySQLdb.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host ' db5010610948.hosting-data.io ' (8)")

Tags: mysql, django

I am trying to connect my django project to a mysql db hosted remotely, I have gotten mysql installed and have configured the settings.py file correctly as far as I can tell even tried adding the wildcard to allowed hosts just to get this to work. but i keep getting:

MySQLdb.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host ' db5010610948.hosting-data.io ' (8)")

when i try to run `python3 manage.py runserver`
not sure where to go from here, I have triple checked to make sure all the info is correct

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'holidaytourney',
        'USER': 'definitelymycorrectusername',
        'PASSWORD': 'definitelymycorrectpassword',
        'HOST': 'db5010610948.hosting-data.io',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

I have tried resetting the db and running the runserver command from a new terminal with no success

Comment: Well, no matter how many times you cheked your settings, the computer where you are running your code cannot resolve the host name provided in the host parameter. We really cannot tell you why that's the case, this is a networking issue, not a programming one.

Comment: Can you ping the hostname (using cmd or anything else that can ping) ?

Answer (score 0):

Per default you can't access a database from outside of IONOS. [Here](https://www.ionos.de/hilfe/hosting/problemloesungen-fuer-php/mysql-datenbank-ist-von-ausserhalb-nicht-erreichbar/) is the according article from the provider.
There are two possible solutions:

1. run your django project directly on your IONOS instance
2. use a root-server from IONOS