Python script to connect to IONOS database
I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database hosted on IONOS using python.
I have tried...
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

# Database connection details
host = 'db5016397412.hosting-data.io'
port = 3306  # Default MySQL port
user = 'dbu1017323'
password = 'my-password'
database = 'dbs13326867'

try:
    # Establish the connection
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=host,
        port=port,
        user=user,
        password=password,
        database=database
    )

    if connection.is_connected():
        print("Successfully connected to the database!")
        
except Error as e:
    print(f"Error connecting to the database: {e}")

and pymysql
both give the error...
Error: 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'db5016397412.hosting-data.io' (11001)

I have php scripts hosted on IONOS which connect with the same credentials without an issue. I'm running my python script on my local machine, is this what is causing the issue?

Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74211799. Read docs on remote access to IONOS. Try running Python scripts hosted on instance like PHP.
